# Getting the proper URL in an angular project

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a working Js plugin thats written in jQuery. For my plugin to work, I need to get the URL, but without the anchor tag that references an element by id. That is, only getting `http://example.com/content/1/` instead of say `http://example.com/content/1/#comments`.

I am doing this with the following function :

```
var getProperURL = function() {
    return window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname;
}
```

This works most of the time. However, I ran this on an angular project, and I only get the protocol and the hostname. How do I do this for AngularJs?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve only the path without the hash, you can use `$location.path()`.

See the official documentation: [location.path()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

> This method is getter / setter.
>
> Return path of current url when called **without any parameter**.
>
> Change path when called with parameter and return $location.
>
> Note: Path **should always begin with forward slash** (/), this method will add the forward slash if it is missing.
>   Return full url representation with all segments encoded according to rules specified in RFC 3986.

Inject `location` and retrieve all datas you need. In the guide is plenty of examples:

```
// given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var path = $location.path();
// => "/some/path"
```

and in your website:

```
// given url http://example.com/content/1/#comments
var path = $location.path();
// => "/content/1"
```